# Find the JFrame an element is in

Tags: java, swing, object, window, jframe

So I have an Object in a JLabel in a JFrame.

I can't alter the JLabel/JFrame's code.

How can I have the Object return the JFrame it's in?

The GUI

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class GUI extends JFrame
{
    public GUI()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(100,50);

        JLabel label = new JLabel(new TestObject().toString());
        label.setBounds(5,5,90,20);
        add(label);

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

My Object

```
public class TestObject
{
    public String toString()
    {
        return "TestObject";
    }
}
```

Something I tried but it printed null

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class TestObject
{
    public TestObject()
    {
        new Bug();
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return "TestObject";
    }
    private class Bug extends Component
    {
        public Bug()
        {
            System.out.println(SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this));
        }
    }
}
```

I can do this but It's assuming I know the title already

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class TestObject
{
    public TestObject()
    {
        for(Window w : Window.getWindows())
        {
            Frame f = (Frame) w;
            if(f.getTitle().equals("hi"))
            {
                JFrame g = (JFrame) f;
                JLabel j = new JLabel("Test");
                j.setBounds(5,20,90,20);
                g.add(j);
                g.repaint();
            }
        }
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return "TestObject";
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I can't alter the JLabel/JFrame's code."*  Unless it is declared `final`  it is possible to `extend` the class.  That often gives almost as much control to alter or expand a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use [SwingUtilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) to help you:

```
SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(Component c)
```

This returns a top level Window object which will be the component's ancestor JFrame ***if*** the component is held by a JFrame. If it's held by a different top level window, such as a JDialog, then this is what will be returned instead. If the component is not yet held by a window, then this will return null as per the [SwingUtilities API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html). Note that you may have to do a little casting (after checking first) if you want to use the object returned in a JFrame-specific way.

Comment: My Object isn't a Component though

Comment: @KonradWright: please clarify then. You state that your object is in a JFrame. How is it "in" the JFrame then if not a component? Please give us some context and perhaps some code.

Comment: I'm working with gridworld code at the moment :/ I'm trying to figure out how get the window the actor is in. But I'll see what I can do to emulate this with simple code.

Comment: @KonradWright: not quite. I don't see what you're trying to test is in what. If the JLabel, then use the method I show above. If a String, then you're out of luck since a String has no knowledge of where it is located.

Comment: What if I were to do something like this?
`
    import java.awt.*;

    import javax.swing.*;

    public class TestObject

    {

        public TestObject()

        {

            new Bug();

        }

        public String toString()

        {

            return "TestObject";

        }

        private class Bug extends Component

        {

            public Bug()
       
            {
            
                  System.out.println(SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this));

            }

        }

    }
`

Comment: @KonradWright: Please post code as an edit to your original question. Never post code like this in comments because it loses all formatting and is impossible to read. Also, rather than ask "what if I were..." please tell us what happens when you *test* your new code.